# QtOpenGL scroll bars not working on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

My intention is to draw using QtOpenGL and to move around the scene using scroll bars.

The weird thing: it works well on windows and linux and it does not work on osx. I suspect that building qt from source may solve this problem.

You may get a copy of following source code(with executables for windows, linux and mac os x) [here](http://www.filedropper.com/code_2).

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtOpenGL>
class GraphicsView: public QGraphicsView {
public:
    GraphicsView(QWidget* parent = 0) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
        if (scene()) {
            scene()->setSceneRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), event->size()));
        }
        QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    }
};
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene {
public:
    void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect) {
        if (painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL && painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2) {
            qWarning("GraphicsScene: drawBackground needs a QGLWidget to be set as viewport on the graphics view");
            return;
        }
        painter->beginNativePainting();
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
        glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(-0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(-0.25, -0.25, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(0.25, -0.25, 0.0);
        glEnd();
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
            glVertex3f(-0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glEnd();
        painter->endNativePainting();
    }
};
class WindowViewer: public QMainWindow {
public:
    WindowViewer() : m_area(this), m_view(this), m_widget(), m_canvas() {
        m_view.setScene(&m_canvas);
        m_view.setViewport(&m_widget);
        m_view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
        m_view.resize(1000, 1000);
        m_area.setWidget(&m_view);
        setCentralWidget(&m_area);
        setWindowTitle("WindowViewer");
        show();
        raise();
    }
    virtual ~WindowViewer(){}
private:
    QScrollArea m_area;
    GraphicsView m_view;
    QGLWidget m_widget;
    GraphicsScene m_canvas;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    WindowViewer w;
    w.resize(800, 600);
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
SOURCES += main.cpp
QT += opengl
```

I have built it on following setups. But many other setups may suffice as well.

OS X 10.9 Mavericks

```
Qt version 4.8.5, QMake version 2.01a
gcc version 4.8.2
```

Ubuntu 12.04

```
Using Qt version 4.8.1, QMake version 2.01a
gcc version 4.8.1
```

Windows 7

```
Qt version 4.8.5, QMake version 2.01a
gcc version 4.8.1
```

Comment: Uhh, a wall of code, I doubt anybody is going to look through it. Try to reduce it (or write new from scratch) to have the smallest possible code which still has the problem. See http://sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Looks much better now! So, the specific question is "why does this work on Linux and Win but not OSX, and how to fix?" ? I suggest you also add [tag:osx] and [tag:qt4] tags (replace [tag:scrolling] tag).

Comment: I took Qt5.2.1, it comes with compiler what simplifies the matter. My code does not work on Mac OS X (Mavericks) and works well on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. What more can I do now?

Comment: Well, hope someone here can answer... Or ask [other places](http://qt-project.org/wiki/OnlineCommunities), or if you think this may actually be a Qt bug, file [a bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa). IRC may work well, if you happen to ask at a time when the right people are around.

Comment: Thank you, hyde. I filed a bug report. https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37546